# the getActiveUser method within a company domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to call `Session.getActiveUser` in order to auto-fill certain fields in a Google Sheets document when other fields are edited.  All users are in the same domain; however, I receive an error message, `"You do not have permission to call getActiveUser."`  I was under the impression from existing documentation that users within the same domain can access one another's information through custom scripts - is this incorrect?  If so, I know that there are several workarounds, but if not, is there something else I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how you are running this code?  Are you using some trigger? Please show an example you are using.

Answer (score 1):

"user3889423" is correct, you need Authorization of the user, in order to call the getActiveUser().

You can find this information in this link below: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced

Answer (score 1):

[The link in KRR's answer contains the information you need](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced). Here's the excerpt answering you question:

- You definitely cannot call `Session.getActiveUser()` without user authorization, even for users within the same domain:

> If your custom function throws the error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

- However, even with user authorization, you still cannot use `Session.getActiveUser()` in custom functions (directly in cells). You need to create a custom menu instead:

> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.

Comment: I also need to find the current user of a sheet. Could anyone provide a minimal working example of a script to get permission from users and how to use it to get the current user information?

Answer (score 0):

If that script runs without the explicit authorization of the user, you won't be able to get the ActiveUser (I think). It should work though when a user authorizes the script first.